# I'm trying to understand how to use struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Heres a snippet of a code I'm playing around with the understand the char inside a struct.

```
typedef struct{
    int mpg;
    int wheels;
    char owner[20];
}desc_t;

typedef struct{
    int price;
    char purchase_location[20];
    desc_t desc;
}car_t;

int main(void)
{
    car_t car;

    printf("enter car purchase location: ");
    scanf("%s", car.purchase_location);

    printf("enter car owner: ");
    scanf("%s", car.desc.owner);
}
```

in both of the structs, owner and purchase_location is stored in an array of character so it makes sensee that when I print, I don't use the '&' sign.

However..

```
typedef struct{
    int mpg;
    int wheels;
    char owner;
}desc_t;

typedef struct{
    int price;
    char purchase_location;
    desc_t desc;
}car_t;

int main(void)
{
    car_t car;

    printf("enter car purchase location: ");
    scanf("%s", &car.purchase_location);

    printf("enter car owner: ");
    scanf("%s", &car.desc.owner);
}
```

In this version, Owner and purchase_location don't have the square brackets allocating memory for the array of characters and I have to put the '&' sign to run it without getting warnings.
I noticed this code outputs the same thing as the snippet of code above.

I thought to declare a string, you need to declare the size of an array too.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Output what? You don't seem to print any members of the `car` variable. Try to print all of its members. Then you should see some change.

Comment: `scanf` needs to accept a reference so it can store the data in that location. If `owner` is a `char[]`, you're already passing a reference (arrays evaluate to a pointer to the first element). If `owner` is a char, you need pass the char by reference.

Comment: "I thought to declare a string, you need to declare the size of an array too". You do. But C doesn't hold your hand to stop you doing bad things. In this case you have given a single `char` which can only store one byte string (the empty string). If anything else is stored the result is undefined behaviour (it may crash, or appear to work, or any other behaviour).

Comment: If your question is as the title states, and you are trying to understand 'struct', I strongly recommend you remove all typedefs until you do understand how to use structs.  The typedefs are an unnecessary distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code working is not sufficient to say that it is correct.

In your second code snippet, `purchase_location` is not a string or an array of characters, it is simply a single character.
The reason you do not get any warning is because of the fact that `scanf` just needs an address. When you put an `&` before a variable name it simply gives the address of the variable (which `scanf` can use to store the user input value at). Now when it comes to arrays, the name of the array without any square brackets or index simply gives the address of the first element of the array, to make it clear look at the below:

Assume we have an `char a[10]`, a would give the address of the first element of the array, `a[0]` would give the value of the first element of the array and if you are following you would know that `&a[0]` would once again give the address of the first element of the array. If we have a `char b`, `&b` is the address of the char variable. Now for `scanf` both `&b` and `a` are just addresses of two char variables, but in truth, they are quite different,

If you tell `scanf` that you are expecting a string by mentioning `%s`, it is going to take the characters you input and put them at the given address, that's it. In your case you were lucky to have that space, I believe.

If you tell `printf` that a variable is a string variable and give it an address it will just take all the characters available in that part of the memory.

The two of these together could be the reason that neither do you get any warnings nor do you find errors in the output. In an other case, that space may not be available, or worse you could overwrite some other data.

Comment: You are correct there, but you need to explain why? Array pointer conversion is the issue. `scanf` expects a pointer to type as a parameter for each conversion. With a non-array type you must take the address of to provide the pointer. An array, on access, is converted to a pointer to the first element subject to 4-exceptions [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). That is the reason for the difference.